# what is the difference between processor consistency model and sequential consistency model?

Tags: consistency

I understand the definition of sequential consistency but I am confused in the following example.

p1: W(x)a
p2:       W(x)b
p3:              R(x)b       R(x)a
p4:                    R(x)b       R(x)a

this  system is sequentially consistent
but the following one is not because p3 and p4 are seeing values of x in different order
p1: W(x)a
p2:       W(x)b
p3:              R(x)a       R(x)b
p4:                    R(x)b       R(x)a

So my doubt is here for system to be SC p3 and p4 should be consistent and see same values of x so thats the definition of Processor consistency.
So how PC and SC are different?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a practical programming question. Your question might be on topic on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ (but check their rules and expectations before posting)

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, there is a total order over the memory actions since every reader sees the writes in the same order (they don't disagree).

Definition of SC:

1. total order over all memory actions over **all memory locations**.
2. the order needs to be consistent with the program order of each of the processes
3. a load must see the most recent write before it in the memory order.

The first example satisfies these conditions and hence it is SC. The example is a lame SC example because only a single memory location is involved. This is actually an example of coherence (coherence -> single memory location, consistency -> multiple memory locations). Coherence can be seen as SC for a single memory location. The definition of Coherence:

1. total order over all memory actions for a **single memory location**.
2. the order needs to be consistent with the program order of each of the processes
3. a load must see the most recent write before it in the memory order.

So everything that is SC is coherent, but nice vice versa.

The following example:

p1: W(x)a p2: W(x)b p3: R(x)a R(x)b p4: R(x)b R(x)a

Since p3 and p4 disagree on the order, there is no total order and hence we have violated the first condition for SC. It also isn't coherent because we even don't have a total order over a single memory location (the first condition for coherence).

The example also isn't PC. With PC the writes to different memory locations issued by different processes can be seen in different orders (look for the IRIW litmus test). So PC doesn't require a total order over all memory locations. But.. it does require coherence.

It could be that there is an inconsistency ;) in the definition of PC. Perhaps the definition in your literature doesn't require coherence and then the last example would be PC. There is a different memory model called PRAM which is PC without coherence requirement. So perhaps your literature is actually referring to PRAM.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_consistency

You might want to check out the following book:

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-031-01764-3

Most of the memory models are covered like SC, coherence, and processor consistency. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.